# Disabling Taskbar Thumbnails for some Documents in MDI Application

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, taskbar

At the moment i'm facing another problem in my application. I have a Main View with a document attached. This view holds many views which also have documents attached. The main View is splitted up into 3 parts. Every part contains a toolbar and a tabcontrol which for the specific operations. And every tabcontrol can hold many documents.

This is how my code looks like, if i'm adding a new View to a specific Tab Control:

```
C_KomponentenDoc* pDoc = (C_KomponentenDoc*) ((CApetlonApp*)AfxGetApp())->m_pTableKomponentenTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(szFile, FALSE);
    C_TableCompView* pCompView = new C_TableCompView;

    if(!pDoc || !pCompView)
        return FALSE;

    pCompView->Create(NULL, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0,0,0,0), &m_TabCtrlH, MAX_ANZ_DATAFILES);

    pDoc->AddView(pCompView);

    m_TabCtrlH.AddTab(pCompView, pFileInfo->m_szName);
```

The problem which i have now, is that every document is shown as a thumbnail in the Taskbar, but i only want to show a Thumbnail of the MainView in the Taskbar. Is it possible to disable the Thumbnail for specific Documents?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at the opportunities provided by `DwmSetWindowAttribute`

Comment: I found an option now which could solve my problem "DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK", but i dont exactly know how to use it now.

Comment: I still dont know how to solve that problem :/

Answer (score 1):

In CYourApp::InitInstance, use EnableTaskbarInteraction(FALSE); to disable thumbnail.